# Rails image broken link

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm trying to link to an image in rails and its not working. I can link to assets/file.css as well as assets/file.js but assets/file.jpg doesnt work.

I tried a fresh rails new project_name and when i open the homepage and the rails logo doesnt show.

As a side question,

How do I get rails to load only the application.js and application.css

I see that if i remove ?body=1 from the URL it compresses them all into one file, but when I view the page using the following code it leaves those files blank and includes them one by one as separate scripts.

```
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application", :media => "all" %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
```

Comment: What do you get in the server logs for the image requests?

Comment: what version of rails are you using, where is this assets folder?

Comment: rails 3.2.1, app/assets/images

Comment: ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/glyphicons-halflings-white.png"):  -- currently that path is wrong but thats because i was trying different paths

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok so that's an expected behavior, you have to use Rails helpers:

```
 <%= image_tag "file.jpg" %>
```

Your css files should be .erb. Within it, use:

```
.class { background-image: url(<%= asset_path 'image.png' %>) }
```

Reference is para 2.2.1 [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#coding-links-to-assets).

Comment: If it's in a stylesheet, add sass to that stylesheet (if not already) and use `image-url`.

Answer (score 2):

I just checked my code and my CSS looks like this:

```
background-image:url(/assets/pinstripes.jpg);
```

with the image uploaded to app/assets/images, of course. This looks like what you're using, but I can't tell for sure.

Comment: In order to automatically reference the md5 hashed filenames in production you should use scss and `image-url` instead. Section 2.2.2: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#coding-links-to-assets

Comment: I didn't know you could do that til I saw the above answer! Will change mine.